overflow-x: hidden not preventing horizontal scrolling in hamburger menu implementation


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
    body {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #C80036;
    }

    .ham-bar{
        background-color: #C80036;
        height: auto;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 20%;
        padding: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -400px;
    }

    .ham-bar ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 80px;
    }

    .ham-bar li{
        list-style: none;
    }

    .ham-bar a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .bar{
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        height: 3px;
        width: 25px;
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        left: 85%;
    }

    .bar:nth-child(1){
        top: 30%;
    }

    .bar:nth-child(3){
        top: 50%;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="nav-bar">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <nav class="ham-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="skills">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>



Description: Overflow issue
I'm implementing a hamburger menu for the first time in my web project using HTML, CSS, and a bit of JavaScript. The menu itself functions correctly: it slides in from the right when triggered. However, I'm facing an issue with horizontal scrolling.
I used "overflow -x:hidden" to stop this scrolling behaviour. But it is not working. The page is still scrollable.

I forgot to link my code snippet . If anyone needs that I can add that .

Post the code please. No one can help you fix your code if you don't provide it. A minimal reproducible example is appreciated.

I Provided the code.

Overflow-x seems working fine in the snippet. Check your code for typos

That's the problem. It works fine in snippet and visual code preview tab. The problem arises when I start it in live server

I solved it guys. I set position of the hamburger menu items as "fixed" and the code worked as expected.
